# USB-C Hub (4+ USB-C ports) for desktop

Tags: usb, hub

Looking for a desktop hub (ie. designed to sit permanently on a desk, not get thrown in my laptop bag) that provides 4+ USB-C ports. There seem to be very few USC-C hubs around and they're all designed for laptops. I don't care if it connects to the PC via USB-C or A.

Ability to provide power and charge at high-speed would be nice too, but not required.

Something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MHHQPZI), but with USB-C instead of A.

Comment: This [Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1381139/899186) is relevant. I don't think any hubs exist yet that provide multiple USB-C ports. The first thing that comes to mind is that USB-C has features that assume it is a 1:1 connection: i.e. Power delivery, video signals, PCIe (TB3). USB Type-C is not a replacement for Type-A, USB devices that don't need things like video or 100W of power delivery will still use USB A connectors, which is why you can find so many C -> A hubs.

Comment: I can find few hubs that *do* split USB-C ports, but they don't support the alternate modes, power delivery, etc. So they're functionally identical to USB A 3.1 ports.

Comment: @Romen - this might be the answer - as of right now, they just don't exist. Depressingly, but looks like that's reality. Not entirely convinced on the "if not video / high power" use USB-A though. Plenty of small things like USB keys, charger cables, already exist as USB-C. What I want is a single plug - USB-C, to work with multiple connections USB 3.1, or Thunderbolt, etc, all using the same plug, so I can just have a single hub and set of cables. Nirvana is both very close, and a long way away, it seems.

Comment: Well Type-C exists in lots of places, so there *will* be accessories made to work with it. But the primary use-case for Type-C accessories is on mobile phones. Laptops and desktops are still being made with type A ports so it's a situation where usually both ports are available, and you'd only buy a Type-C usb key or accessory if you needed it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on Stack Exchange’s “Super User” fourm. This is ***taken directly*** from the post in “Super User”, ‘The chips don’t exist currently’. It is possible for this to be a thing, but USB-C is too new of a technology for this to be out yet. I’d expect this to be thing (assuming the COVID-19 outbreak ends before the end of Q2 in 2020 and the world doesn’t go into a recession, which statistically it will just based on the US stock market) in the end of Q4 in 2020 or sometime in 2021. Paraphrasing the “Super User” post again, ‘Intel is leading this technology of making a chip that can handle 1x USB-C to 2x+ USB-C’

[SE Super User: Why can’t I find a USB-C hub with Multiple USB-C ports](https://superuser.com/questions/1381139/why-cant-i-find-a-usb-c-hub-with-multiple-usb-c-ports/1414046)

(Pardon the formatting, I am tired and not on a PC where I could format this a lot better than this. Thank you in advance to whoever edits this answer, I greatly appreciate it)

Comment: That's the same link @Romen found, but appears to be still correct. Annoying given it's a year old link at this point, and I was hoping something had changed.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.hummingbirdnetworks.com/tripp-lite-u460-004-2a2c gives you two USB-C out ports with 1.5A power each port, as does https://zendure.com/products/superport-4-silver-us .  Unable to find a four USB-C port device.